# FFT interpretation

Tags: java, android, accelerometer, fft

I am wokring on an Android project where I am using FFT for processing accelerometer data and I have problems understanding how are these things actually working.
I am using jTransform library by Piotr Wendykier in the following way:

```
        int length = vectors.length;
        float[] input = new float[length*2];
        for(int i=0;i<length;i++){
            input[i]=vectors[i];
        }

        FloatFFT_1D fftlib = new FloatFFT_1D(length);
        fftlib.complexForward(input);

        float outputData[] = new float[(input.length+1)/2];
        if(input.length%2==0){
            for(int i = 0; i < length/2; i++){

                outputData[i]= (float) Math.sqrt((Math.pow(input[2*i],2))+(Math.pow(input[2*(i)+1], 2)));
            }
        }else{
            for(int i = 0; i < length/2+1; i++){

                outputData[i]= (float) Math.sqrt((Math.pow(input[2*i],2))+(Math.pow(input[2*i+1], 2)));
            }
        }

        List<Float> output = new ArrayList<Float>();
        for (float f : outputData) {
            output.add(f);
        }
```

the result is an array with following data [image: output data visualization].

I have problem with interpreting the output data..The data are from 10 seconds long interval, and the sampling frequency is 50Hz..While capturing I was moving the phone up and down cca each 3/4 second in my hand, so is possible that the extreme which is about x value 16 could be the period of the strongest component of the signal?
I need to obtain the frequency of the strongest component in the signal..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The frequency represented by each fft result bin is the bin number times the sample rate divided by the length of the fft (convolved with a Sinc function giving it non-zero width, to get a bit technical).  If your sample rate is 50 Hz and your fft's lenght is fft length is 512, then bin 16 of the fft result would represent about 1.6 Hz which is close to having a period of 0.7 seconds.

The spike at bin 0 (DC) might represent the non-zero force of gravity on the accelerometer.

Comment: Gravity has no effect on an accelerometer...  The spike at DC is likely to simply be an output bias on the sensor, or even simply that the integral of the device acceleration over the measurement window was not zero (in other words, there was a net change in velocity).

Comment: @Oli : Interesting. The accelerometer on my iPhone lying on the desk reports a constant -1 on the Z axis.  The direction of the -1 is how device orientation is determined.  Is Android different?

Comment: Hmm, I don't know anything about the sensors used in phones, so I retract my previous statement!  However, I would find the name "accelerometer" a bit misleading if it was designed to report non-zero when the device was stationary.

Comment: @Oli : Lookup the meaning of equivalence in Einstein's General Theory of Relativity.

Comment: So, playing devil's advocate, is there a generally accepted way to tune out the initial noise?  Or is that a hardware specific 'feature?'

Comment: on Android there is couple of SENSOR modes..I use linear acceleration http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Sensor.html, so that there should be no gravity at all..when using other types I get values like cca 9.8 m/s^2..Sensor returns me an array with three values, each for one axis..That I process like sqrt(values[0]^2+values[1]^2+values[2]^2)..
I see the graph is unfortunately very small, co here is it bigger http://cl.ly/3r2J2K2p3M02321a2o37

Comment: Good to mention is that my input array which I put into the fft is half-empty, because as I figured out, the library works in place, and since it output both imaginary and real part I need twice as slots in my array..this is kind of weird I think, but interesting is also, that the first element in output arrray is everytime just huge in comparison with others..unfortunately I didnt find any good docs for the library..

Answer (score 1):

Since you have the real data, you should pass these values to realForward function (not `complexForward`) as stated [here](http://incanter.org/docs/parallelcolt/api/edu/emory/mathcs/jtransforms/fft/DoubleFFT_1D.html#realForward%28double%5B%5D%29).